# Update NuGet MVC packages and pre-processed files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

Related to: [Package an ASP.NET MVC application with Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899847/package-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-nuget)

I'm trying to get a mode where I can edit an MVC project and package it easily.
As often suggested it is wise to replace a namespace using NuGet pre-processor functionality.

This would mean that I would have to edit my source files and add the pp extensions to each pre-processed source file.

Are there any tips and tricks to make this less labourious?

Answer (score 0):

There is such a tool, that did almost exactly what I wanted. It's on Codeplex so I could participate in the development, yay!

https://nugetpackager.codeplex.com/

It has a common-line interface too, so I can script my updates.